# Query issue for a forum done in ReactJS MySQL Node.js and Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am a junior developer and right now I’m building a simple forum using ReactJS, Node.js, Express and MySQL.

In the forum each Topic must have many many Posts.

I do not know if the problem comes from the back-end query or if it comes from the client side but the posts aren’t well separated per topic.
Right now I have all the posts from the posts table in topic 1 and again in topic 2.

[Test Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8zwB.png)

In the server folder here are my imports in index.js

[Server side imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZHCR.png)

and here are my queries for Posts.

[Server side queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpjJc.png)

Thank you for any help.

Have a very nice day,
Ana

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems ok, which will return all records by inner join with topics table.
One more suggestion, use the below code to get the proper HTTP response code.

`return res.status(200).send(result);`

Also, use try...catch to handle exceptions as well.